# How can i package jar so that dependent spring jars wont include in my final jar instead refer them to a maven repository

Tags: spring, gradle, spring-boot

Trying to build a jar with Gradle which has some spring dependencies and put in a nexus repository. and My build.gradle looks like below

```
dependencies {

compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jdbc', version: '3.1.0.RELEASE'



compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-spring-service-connector:1.2.2.RELEASE")
compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector:1.2.2.RELEASE")

  }
```

When i bundle my jar using this it just includes these jars in my final jar.

```
jar {
baseName = 'npswo-framework'
version =  '0.1.0'
from {
    configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
}


 }
```

I am looking for something where my final jar should have some reference to these jars may be through META-INF and download them when someone download my jar.

Currently if someone download or refer my jar in nexus it includes spring jar folders under my jar and they are being duplicated if the project already has spring reference

Comment: why at all do you do so instead of simply let grade package the jar with its normal contents by removing the whole from part? my jar {} config normally only contains a manifest part

Comment: normally the dependencies are stored in the pom.xml. To enable this add the 'maven-publish' plugin

Comment: If you look at any standard jar of Spring it will have its  own content (classes) and dependent jars in meta-inf pom.xml i want to build the jar in same way with Gradle . for example you can refer spring-data-rest-mvc jar it has its own classes and pom.xml in metainf/maven/... if some one pull this jar along with rest-mvc all other jars also gets added .

Comment: Yes, the pom is created by the maven-publish plugin. It will be deployed independent to a repository

Comment: Thanks @ArneBurmeister it helped me a lot .maven publish gradle worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven publish plugin in gradle resolved the issue , We can follow any example of creating publish plugin in gradle